# show first record in array on index.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an Image model that is linked by a many-to-one relationship with the Post model.

On the index action I would like to display only the first image.  `@post.images.each` works well but `@post.image.first` does not.  So what I am wondering is: while in the view how does one display only the first record from the images array?

Comment: what does not work mean?  is there an error , what is the unexpected result?

Comment: use `@post.images[0]` or `@post.images.first`

Answer (score 2):

As you have a many-to-one relationship:

- `@post.images` (with a 's') is a collection of images
- `@post.image` (without 's') does not exist

So to get the first image you must use: `@post.images.first` (with a 's')

Comment: ive tried this a couple of ways and Im getting no method errors. the first try was in a do block '<% post.images[0] do |image| %>  <%= image_tag image.file_url %><% end %>' and the next attempt was just prefacing the field I wanted to display '<%=post.images[0].post_id %>'  I guess the question should really be: how do I show only the first image from the images collection

Comment: To the question "how do I show only the first image from the images collection" my answer is you must use: `@post.images.first`