# Printing First Photo in Array with Ruby/ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I'm trying to show just the first photo in an array, but for some reason it's not behaving as I expect it to.  I consulted [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23588205/show-first-record-in-array-on-index-html-erb), but something isn't working.  When I put:

```
<% listing.listing_property_details.images.each do |image_url| %>
     <%= image_tag image_url, class: "fancy-border" %>
<% end %>
```

It displays five images (the entire array).  However, when I change `each` to `first` (as was recommended in the consulted SO posts) all the images disappear.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= image_tag listing.listing_property_details.images.first, class: "fancy-border" %>
```

Comment: In your code that you posted, you are going through an array of image URLs, passing each of them to `image_tag`, here I just take the first URL and pass it to `image_tag`

Comment: Yes, I see that, I just don't see why that works if changing `each` to `first` in the original code didn't.  Either way, thank you for the fix.

Comment: Because `.first` returns a string, while `.each` returns an `Enumerator` that you can pass a block to

Comment: @Liz because `first` does not take a block as an argument and your block is just discarded, because it's never used.